# Unity 3D Vs 3DS Max Default Models Colors Variance

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, 3ds

I was getting 3d models color difference in 3DS Max (My 3d models designing software) compare to Unity (My game development engine). For your reference, I have taken one example screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

In 3DS Max, its looking lighter and in cool colors. In Unity 3D, its looking darker and shiny colors.
If I check color code in Unity 3d, then it's proper it should require to look same but then why I was seeing all things in cool colors in 3DS Max!!!

In all 3d models, I was getting this kind of color difference when I import within the Unity game engine.
Because of this, the creation of an environment look and feel become really difficult for me.

In the above example, in both software, I didn't change any kind of default settings related to lighting or anything else. 
What to do in this case for getting the exact same thing from 3DS Max to Unity 3D?

Comment: Because there are different software, different graphic settings, different shaders, if you import the model into maya I guess you will get another picture.

Comment: materials are not universally compatible, to be honest both of your screenshots look relatively similar (all things considered)

Comment: @shingo then on each model, shall I require to apply updated material to make it similar to 3ds max? At present Unity showing all things much darker and in shiny colors

Comment: Try to adjust the light direction color and intensity. the shadow under the car shows the light is not as same as it in 3ds max.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Gamma correction in 3ds Max:
Rendering menu -> Gamma/LUT setup... -> Gamma and LUT tab -> Uncheck "Enable Gamma/LUT Correction" checkbox.

Default gamma of 2.2 can make colors appear washed out.  This is actually important in a lot of architectural and realistic rendering scenarios, but not necessarily needed for games.

In Photoshop, increasing the "Unity" side of your image to a gamma of 2.2 seems to produce more consistent colors with the "3ds Max" side.  However, there are also differences in lighting, light angle, and background color.

Answer (score 0):

In the materials settings in Unity you can control which objects receive and cast shadows. It looks like some of your models aren't receiving or casting shadows. I'd also try to adjust the light directions like some of the other users said.

Also it should be easy to change the skybox from the light blue to a black in the Camera settings to match your max scene.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is likely a lot of reasons, from material settings, lighting settings etc. One thing you can try is to switch your Unity Project from Gamma Space to Linear Space, 
Edit>Project Settings>Player->Color Space. Linear Space usually improves the look in your scene allowing your objects to brighten linearly.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LinearRendering-LinearOrGammaWorkflow.html

[image]